# Calculate Execution Times in Sort algorithm

Tags: c++, time-complexity, quicksort, mergesort

I implemented Merge Sort and Quick Sort in C++, and I wanna get the execution times using each of two with many of cases those are already Sorted or not & has different size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void Merge(vector<int>& s, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = low;
    vector<int> u(s);

    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (s.at(i) < s.at(j)) {
            u.at(k) = s.at(i);
            i++;
        } else {
            u.at(k) = s.at(j);
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    if (i > mid) {
        for (int a = j; a < high + 1; a++) {
            u.at(k) = s.at(a);
            k++;
        }
    } else {
        for (int a = i; a < mid + 1; a++) {
            u.at(k) = s.at(a);
            k++;
        }
    }
    for (int a = low; a < high + 1; a++)
        s.at(a) = u.at(a);
}

void MergeSort(vector<int>& s, int low, int high) {
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        MergeSort(s, low, mid);
        MergeSort(s, mid + 1, high);
        Merge(s, low, mid, high);
    }
}

void swap(int& a, int& b) {
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}

void Partition(vector<int>& s, int low, int high, int& pvpoint) {
    int j;
    int pvitem;

    pvitem = s.at(low);
    j = low;
    for (int i = low + 1; i <= high; i++) {
        if (s.at(i) < pvitem) {
            j++;
            swap(s.at(i), s.at(j));
        }
        pvpoint = j;
        swap(s.at(low), s.at(pvpoint));
    }
}

void QuickSort(vector<int>& s, int low, int high) {
    int pvpoint;
    if (high > low) {
        Partition(s, low, high, pvpoint);
        QuickSort(s, low, pvpoint - 1);
        QuickSort(s, pvpoint + 1, high);
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> CaseSize(20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //10 Arrays those are sorted
        CaseSize.at(i) += (i + 1) * 500;
    }

    for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) { //rest 10 those are not sorted
        CaseSize.at(i) += (i + 1) * 5000;
    }

    cout << "------------------Sorted------------------\n\n";
    cout << "      Quick Sort       Merge Sort\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vector<int> Arr(CaseSize.at(i));
        Arr.front() = rand() % Arr.size();
        for (int j = 1; j < Arr.size(); j++) {
            Arr.at(j) = ((17 * Arr.at(j - 1) + 43) % (Arr.size() * 5));
        }
        vector<int> Arr2(Arr);

        sort(Arr.begin(), Arr.end());
        sort(Arr2.begin(), Arr2.end());

        cout << "N : " << CaseSize.at(i) << "    ";
        clock_t start = (int)clock();
        QuickSort(Arr, 0, Arr.size() - 1);
        printf("%0.5fms", (float)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        cout << "\t\t";

        clock_t start2 = (int)clock();
        MergeSort(Arr2, 0, Arr2.size() - 1);
        printf("%0.5fms", (float)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------Random------------------\n\n";
    cout << "        Quick Sort     Merge Sort\n";
    for (int k = 10; k < 20; k++) {
        vector<int> Arr(CaseSize.at(k));
        Arr.front() = rand() % Arr.size();
        for (int l = 1; l < Arr.size(); l++) {
            Arr.at(l) = ((17 * Arr.at(l - 1) + 43) % (Arr.size() * 5));
        }
        vector<int> Arr2(Arr);

        cout << "N : " << CaseSize.at(k) << "    ";

        clock_t start = (int)clock();
        QuickSort(Arr, 0, Arr.size() - 1);
        printf("%0.5fms", (float)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        cout << "\t\t";

        clock_t start2 = (int)clock();
        MergeSort(Arr2, 0, Arr2.size() - 1);
        printf("%0.5fms", (float)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Well, the program worked actually, but the execution time printed was not like what I expected.
Did I do all right? I wanna run both algorithms to show their execution times and so I could compare their **TIME COMPLEXITY** in this way (without fixing sort algorithm as much as possible).

Comment: What did it print and what did you expect?

Comment: `vector<int> CaseSize(20);` -- This is way too small of a test case.  Even using a bubble sort, the time taken will be instantaneous.  You need thousands, if not millions of elements.

Comment: To plot time complexity you need multiple values of *N* involved. There's only one here. Try with 20, 200, 2000, 20000, etc. increasing by a power fo ten each time.

Comment: Also if you want to see that the quick sort is much slower because its worst case is `O(n^2)` and the one for merge sort `O(n*log(n))`. But this doesn't make much differenc in a random test, because the avarage-case for quick sort is `O(n*log(n))`

Comment: Also make sure you are using compiler optimisations

Comment: Your merge sort copies its input, which increases the time complexity. You should merge in-place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your merge sort algorithm is **very** inefficient: `Merge` makes a copy of the whole array at the start of each recursive call, a quadratic cost.

The quick sort implementation is also pathologically slow in some very common cases: if the array is already sorted, the pivot value is always the smallest element in the slice, so the recursion depth is the length of the array and you get quadratic time complexity if not a *stack overflow*.

It is difficult to tell without measuring which if these inefficiencies will hurt performance the most, but I would guess `MergeSort` is the loser.

Also if you want to print milliseconds, use this expression:

```
printf("%0.5fms", (clock() - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

To fix the problem in `Merge`, modify the code to create a vector of the correct size:

```cpp
void Merge(vector<int>& s, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = 0;
    vector<int> u(high + 1 - low);

    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (s.at(i) < s.at(j)) {
            u.at(k) = s.at(i);
            i++;
        } else {
            u.at(k) = s.at(j);
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    if (i > mid) {
        while (j <= high) {
            u.at(k) = s.at(j);
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    } else {
        while (i <= mid) {
            u.at(k) = s.at(i);
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    for (i = low, k = 0; i <= high; i++, k++)
        s.at(i) = u.at(k);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate for your answer!! Actually, I think i still cannot see accurate time in here(I'm trying in Putty and Visual Studio both), so I think I should fix more

Comment: @qkekehrtnfl97:  Timing code precisely is a difficult art. Among other traps and pitfalls, you should avoid producing output until all tests have completed. Store the elapsed clock values in an array and output the timing table in a loop after all tests have completed. You should also check if the sorting functions completed correctly with a loop checking that the arrays are sorted. You can also benchmark the C++ `sort` template function for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. First you need to add include <time.h>.
You can get execution time for different algorithms through the following:
x is the size of the array.

```
include <time.h>
int main(){
struct timeval stop,start;
int arr[x];
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    arr[i]=i+1;
printf("This is the Array created with sorted integer(Sorted  Data)\n\n");
gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
selectionSort(arr,x);
gettimeofday(&stop,NULL);
printf("Time taken for selection sort is: %ld microseconds\n",(stop.tv_sec- 
start.tv_sec)*1000000+stop.tv_usec-start.tv_usec);

gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
bubbleSort(arr,x);
gettimeofday(&stop,NULL);
printf("Time taken for Bubble sort is: %ld microseconds\n",(stop.tv_sec- 
start.tv_sec)*1000000+stop.tv_usec-start.tv_usec);

gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
quickSort(arr,0,9999);
gettimeofday(&stop,NULL);
printf("Time taken for Quick sort is: %ld microseconds\n",(stop.tv_sec- 
start.tv_sec)*1000000+stop.tv_usec-start.tv_usec);

gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
heapSort(arr,x);
gettimeofday(&stop,NULL);
printf("Time taken for Heap sort is: %ld microseconds\n",(stop.tv_sec- 
start.tv_sec)*1000000+stop.tv_usec-start.tv_usec);
}
```